# Get Exchange user PrimarySmtpAddress for DisplayType olForum

Tags: c#, outlook, exchange-server

From an [AddressEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.addressentry.aspx) instance I'm calling [GetExchangeUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.addressentry.getexchangeuser.aspx) or [GetExchangeDistributionList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.addressentry.getexchangedistributionlist.aspx) methods to get `PrimarySmtpAddress`. This works fine when the `AddressEntry` has a `DisplayType` of `olUser` or `olDistList`, but both return null for an address with `DisplayType` of `olForum`.

The Exchange address *does* have an associated SMTP address. In Outlook I can type the address into "To" on a new email and it resolves to the appropriate Exchange user. Double-click on the user and an SMTP address does show. I just can't find a way to get to it through the Outlook object model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the SMTP address is available on that address entry, you should be able to retrieve it using `AddressEntry.PropetyAccessor.GetProperty`.

Take a look at that address entry using [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author) - if you already have a message with that GAL entry as one of the recipients, select it in Outlook, click IMessage button on the OutlookSpy ribbon, go to the GetRecipientTable tab, double click on the recipient.

Do you see `PR_SMTP_ADDRESS` property? How about `PR_EMS_AB_PROXY_ADDRESSES`? Both properties can be retrieved using `AddressEntry.PropetyAccessor.GetProperty`

Comment: Without having gone to the extent of using OutlookSpy, I found that yes, it does have the PR_SMTP_ADDRESS property. And [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff868695.aspx) pointed me in the direction of the schema tag to use - http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E

Comment: Keep in mind that PR_SMTP_ADDRESS might not be always available, especially in the cached mode. PR_EMS_AB_PROXY_ADDRESSES seems to be always available.

Comment: In my development environment (OL2013, cached mode) I seem to be getting a value for PR_SMTP_ADDRESS consistently, but PR_EMS_AB_PROXY_ADDRESSES fails every time. To be safe, I'll code to fall-back from one to the other in case of failure.

Comment: It is usually the other way around. How are you retrieving the PR_EMS_AB_PROXY_ADDRESSES property? Keep in mind that it is a multivalued string property (you will get back an array).

Comment: Where `senderUser` is of type `Outlook.Recipient`, I am calling `senderUser.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x800F101E")` and getting a "Object does not support property" exception. Thanks for pointing out that it returns an array, without being able to find an instance that returns the property it's proving impossible to debug.