# VSTO Outlook.Recipients Value Displaying External Email Addresses Differently than Internal Email Addresses

Tags: vb.net, vsto, outlook-addin

We have an Outlook VSTO Add-In that is checking the Outlook.Recipients domain to see if the addressee is going external to our network

```
Dim objRecipients As Outlook.Recipients
```

So say there are 2 recipients that we want to loop through and check the domain:

```
Do While objRecipients.Count >= loopCount
  If InStr(1, objRecipients(loopCount).Address, "@") Then
    ...
  End If
  Loop +=1
Loop
```

For an external objRecipient(loopCount).Address we're seeing, say:

```
  gmail.com
```

Which is good.

However, for internal addresses, we seem to be seeing LDAP/Exchange addresses instead of SMTP addresses like this:

```
/O=EXCHANGELABS/OU=EXCHANGE ADMINISTRATIVE GROUP (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/CN=RECIPIENTS/CN=9asd9asd9d9d9asd9asd9asd9asd9asd9asd-Fred Smith"
```

This seemed to just start happening, but not sure why or how to fix this problem.

Any idea of why this occurs?

Thanks

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19443087/get-exchange-user-primarysmtpaddress-for-displaytype-olforum

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44178822/how-to-get-senders-email-address-if-user-is-an-active-directory-user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following this article helped us fix our issue:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/Concepts/Address-Book/obtain-the-e-mail-address-of-a-recipient

We needed to use the Outlook.PropertyAccessor property to get the correct SMTP Address:

```
  Dim objRecipients As Outlook.Recipients

  Dim pa As Outlook.PropertyAccessor
  Const PR_SMTP_ADDRESS As String = 
  "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E"

        Do While objRecipients.Count >= loopCount

            'set propertyaccessor object
            pa = objRecipients(loopCount).PropertyAccessor

           'set propertyaccessor domain based on smtp address
           paDomain = pa.GetProperty(PR_SMTP_ADDRESS)

           Loop +=1
 Loop
```